# Python regular expression to search a string

Tags: python, regex

I've the below code:

```
def ospf_route_type_E2_exists(nbr_output,AS_ext_net_list,net_list):
    match_list=[]
    if type(AS_ext_net_list) is not list:
        AS_ext_net_list=[AS_ext_net_list]
    if type(net_list) is not list:
        net_list=[net_list]
    for ext_net,net in zip(AS_ext_net_list,net_list):
        net_prefix=str(net).rstrip(".0")
        match= re.search(r"O[" "]+E2[" "]+str\(ext_net\)[" "]+\[[0-9]*[0-9]*[0-9]+\/[0-9]+\][" "]+via[" "]+str(net_prefix)",nbr_output)
        match_list.append(match)
    if any(item for item in match_list):
        print "AS External networks properly advertised via correct areas"
        return 1
    else:
        print "AS External networks not properly advertised via correct areas"
        return 0
```

The nbr_ouput will contain below:

```
show ip route ospf 
O IA 192.168.42.0/24 [110/2] via 192.168.43.4, 00:00:29, FastEthernet0/0
O    192.168.124.0/24 [110/2] via 192.168.43.4, 00:00:29, FastEthernet0/0
    10.0.0.0/24 is subnetted, 1 subnets
O E2    10.1.1.0 [110/1] via 192.168.43.4, 00:00:29, FastEthernet0/0
```

I want to search for the line:

```
O E2    10.1.1.0 [110/1] via 192.168.43.4, 00:00:29, FastEthernet0/0
```

using the match line as in my code:

```
 match= re.search(r"O[" "]+E2[" "]+str\(ext_net\)[" "]+\[[0-9]*[0-9]*[0-9]+\/[0-9]+\][" "]+via[" "]+str(net_prefix)",nbr_output)
```

Expected output:

```
        print "AS External networks properly advertised via correct areas"
        return 1
```

Output that I get:

```
        print "AS External networks not properly advertised via correct areas"
        return 0
```

Which tells me that my regular expression search doesn't work. Please let me know what am I doing wrong

Comment: Why do you have quotes in `[" "]`? There are no quotes in the strings you're trying to match.

Comment: You can use `\d` to match digits instead of `[0-9]`. And `[0-9]*[0-9]*[0-9]+` makes no sense to repeat them, it should just be `[0-9]+`.

Comment: I'm trying to match at least one or multiple occurrence of space. Am I doing it wrong ? Should it be just ` [  ]+` ? Other than this is everything fine ?

Comment: You have `str(net_prefix)` at the end of the regexp. That doesn't appear anywhere in the string, what is it supposed to match?

Comment: You don't need the brackets at all, just  `\s+`

Comment: `+ str(net_prefix)` needs to be outside the quotes, so it will be executed and concatenated. Inside the quotes it's just literal text to be matched.

Comment: Couldn't you just use a string `find` method to match the row that has "E2"?

Comment: @Barmar I used `match= re.search(r"O\s+E2\s+"+str(ext_net)+"\s+\[[0-9]+\/[0-9]+\]\s+via\s+"+str(net_prefix),nbr_output)` and it works. Thanks much for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I used:

```
match= re.search(r"O\s+E2\s+"+str(ext_net)+"\s+\[[0-9]+\/[0-9]+\]\s‌​+via\s+"+str(net_pre‌​fix),nbr_output)
```

and it works.